# Bit manipulation, insertion, binary

Tags: c++

I am not sure why some of the code is not formatting properly, so I apologize if this is difficult to read. I am learning C++ for one of my classes, but I am stuck. I have very little knowledge of this language, so I honestly don't know what's wrong or what to do next.

The program is supposed to take four parameters, a binary number, a second binary number, a position number, and number of bits from the new number. It is supposed to take the first (num of bits) from the new number and insert them into the original at position (short).

The goal is to make the tests at the bottom pass. I managed to remove all of the error messages, but the tests aren't passing so I must have made a logic error somewhere.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

  // Return the altered bits of "input" 
// where the first "numBits" of "newBits" (unspecified bits are 0)
// replace "input" bits starting at "position"

unsigned char set_bits_to(
    unsigned char input, 
    unsigned char newBits, 
    short position, 
    short numBits){
//Your Code Here

    unsigned char insert; 
    int x;
    int i;
    int q = 0;

    if (input < 225) {
        bitset<4> o(input);
        bitset<4> d(newBits);


        for (x = 0; x < numBits; x++) {
            insert = o[position] = d[q];
            q++;
            position = position + 1;
        }

    }


    //  else {
    //      bitset<8> x(input);
    //  }(input )
    //bitset<8> x(input);



  //Stop Code Here        
};

int main() {

    assert(set_bits_to(0b1111, 0b0, 0, 1) == 0b1110);
    assert(set_bits_to(0b1111, 0b0, 1, 1) == 0b1101);
    assert(set_bits_to(0b1111, 0b0, 0, 3) == 0b1000);

    assert(set_bits_to(0b11001100, 0b101, 2, 3) == 0b11010100);
    assert(set_bits_to(0b11001100, 0b101, 2, 5) == 0b10010100);
    assert(set_bits_to(0b11001100, 0b101, 3, 3) == 0b11101100);
    assert(set_bits_to(0b11001100, 0b101, 5, 3) == 0b10101100);

    assert(set_bits_to(0b1111, 0b101010, 0, 6) == 0b101010);
    assert(set_bits_to(0b1111, 0b101010, 1, 6) == 0b1010101);
    assert(set_bits_to(0b1111, 0b101010, 0, 3) == 0b1010);

    cout << "All tests passed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would it contain b in it? Idk why that would work. Also, you've no return statement.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, my apologies. I had a return statement, but I moved it when I was trying to figure out something. I guess I forgot to put it back.

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution:

```
char insert = (~0 << numOfBits) & newBits; // these bits would be inserted
// this piece of code cleans bits between position and position - numOfBits
char positioned = ((~0 << position) | // preserves bits from position to MSB 
     ~(~0 << (position - numOfBits)) // preservs bits from position to LSB
         & input;
input = positioned & insert << position;
```

Comment: I attempted the method that you provided, and thankfully no error messages. Unfortunately, the tests are still failing. I have been trying to find a C++ program to run a debugger so I could walk through the code and see what it is doing, but I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: I ran through the code and made it print out the first value and it is coming out to 1111 ---> 0000. Which isn't actually incorrect, it's just missing the first value, should be 1000.